# STM32f105 BLT instruction relocates a local variable

Tags: c, assembly, arm, embedded, stm32

Using Keil uVison 4 on Windows 7 I have a c project for stm32f105 that is showing very strange behaviour. I checked it up with a debugger, and after several hours error chasing I localized the error to comming from an already tested in other projects function. Which looked like that:

```
uint8_t can_add_filter_mask(can_t* this, uint32_t id, uint32_t id_mask, can_frm_type_t type, can_frm_type_t type_mask)
{
  CAN_FilterInitTypeDef filt;

    /* Empty filter available? */
    if(this->filter_len >= 14)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    /* Select filter number */
    if(this->canx == CAN1)
        filt.CAN_FilterNumber = this->filter_len + 0;
    else
        filt.CAN_FilterNumber = this->filter_len + 14;
    this->filter_len++;

    ...
    //filt is read
    CAN_FilterInit(&filt);
}
```

It was so that the structure filt is not changed after any of the assigments! Then I changed the dissassembly and it's the following (I'm sorry that it's a bit long):

```
   108: uint8_t can_add_filter_mask(can_t* this, uint32_t id, uint32_t id_mask, can_frm_type_t type, can_frm_type_t type_mask) 
0x08001B22 BD70      POP      {r4-r6,pc}
   109: { 
   110:   CAN_FilterInitTypeDef filt; 
   111:  
   112:         /* Empty filter available? */ 
0x08001B24 E92D41FF  PUSH     {r0-r8,lr}
0x08001B28 4604      MOV      r4,r0
0x08001B2A 460D      MOV      r5,r1
0x08001B2C 4690      MOV      r8,r2
0x08001B2E 461E      MOV      r6,r3
0x08001B30 9F0A      LDR      r7,[sp,#0x28]
   113:         if(this->filter_len >= 14) 
   114:         { 
0x08001B32 7C20      LDRB     r0,[r4,#0x10]
0x08001B34 280E      CMP      r0,#0x0E
0x08001B36 DB03      BLT      0x08001B40
   115:                 return FALSE; 
0x08001B38 2000      MOVS     r0,#0x00
   151: } 
   152:  
   153: /******************************************************************************/ 
   154: void can_clr_filter(can_t* this) 
0x08001B3A B004      ADD      sp,sp,#0x10
0x08001B3C E8BD81F0  POP      {r4-r8,pc}
   119:         if(this->canx == CAN1) 
0x08001B40 4970      LDR      r1,[pc,#448]  ; @0x08001D04
0x08001B42 6820      LDR      r0,[r4,#0x00]
0x08001B44 4288      CMP      r0,r1
0x08001B46 D103      BNE      0x08001B50
   120:                 filt.CAN_FilterNumber = this->filter_len + 0; 
   121:         else 
0x08001B48 7C20      LDRB     r0,[r4,#0x10]
0x08001B4A F88D000A  STRB     r0,[sp,#0x0A]
0x08001B4E E004      B        0x08001B5A
   122:                 filt.CAN_FilterNumber = this->filter_len + 14; 
0x08001B50 7C20      LDRB     r0,[r4,#0x10]
0x08001B52 300E      ADDS     r0,r0,#0x0E
0x08001B54 B2C0      UXTB     r0,r0
0x08001B56 F88D000A  STRB     r0,[sp,#0x0A]
   123:         this->filter_len++; 
   124:  
   125:         /* Select mask mode */ 
0x08001B5A 7C20      LDRB     r0,[r4,#0x10]
0x08001B5C 1C40      ADDS     r0,r0,#1
0x08001B5E 7420      STRB     r0,[r4,#0x10]
```

I'm not an assembly expert, neither an ARM expert, but I have been programing a bit on assembly and to me it doesn't look bad. What I noticed that was a bit strange was that in between was part of another function can_clr_filter, so it looked like the compiler was reusing some code, though any optimizations are turned off. The interesting part was that when I checked the address of the `filt.CAN_FilterNumber` variable, it changed after the line

```
0x08001B36 DB03      BLT      0x08001B40
```

from address 0x20002262 to address 0x20002252. So all changes were applied just somewhere else in the memory!! The problem has dissapear after I had declared the variable as static, though it's a mistery to me what actually happened... How could it be that a local variable is relocated to another address by the instruction BLT? Or could the uVision debugger show the wrong reference value by watching the &filt.CAN_FilterNumber?

Comment: Did you check that `this` was non-`NULL`  to begin with, and pointing at a valid address? Is there any risk of a stack overflow, i.e. where in the current task's stack are you located and is there room to spare? `BLT` in itself shouldn't use stack, but if you're already out strange things might happen.

Comment: @unwind, I did. {this} is not 'NULL', because 'this->canx' has the same address as the global var CAN2 - meaning that 'this' was already succesfuly initialized. The stack is 1KB big. It could be of course the problem. How to find that out?

Comment: @judoka_acl to rule out stack overflow, you can put a canary value to the bottom of allocated stack memory, like some `0xdeadf00d` word, and then keep checking in some main loop whether the canary is alive (i.e. that memory still contains the initial value). Once the stack will grow out of the allocated space, it will also overwrite the canary value (it will be difficult to find the origin :/). Some compilers afford similar/better technique for debug builds, checking stack validity even around every function call, but your trivial manual canary may be fast enough even for production builds.

Comment: @Ped7g is the stack size not calculated during compilation? Won't the compiler output errors or warnings when the required stack size is bigger than the allocated?

Comment: @judoka_acl not sure about it, but I think it would be possible to transform any code in turing-machine-like way to be fully stack-based, then if you would be capable to calculate exact stack usage in P(n) time, you would be basically able to solve the halting problem... which is known to be NP-complete. I'm not aware of any compiler capable to do any deep stack analysis during compilation, usually the programmer sets up the stack size (compiler options or linker script), or OS like windows grow it dynamically when the app runs out of initially reserved space. Trivial size checks are possible.

Comment: what were you using to "check the address" of the variable, particularly at runtime?  being on the stack might make sense as a local variable, adding static makes it a "local global" moves it from the stack to .bss in this case where it wont move.  BLT cant change the address  but maybe your stack pointer changed and the debugger is confused about using it as an offset.

Comment: @old_timer checked the address by watching the &filt.CAN_FilterNumber.

Comment: @old_timer is it possible that the uVision is showing the wrong reference address of the local variable?

Comment: uVision is software, can have bugs, etc...

Comment: @old_timer everything that run on a processor is software...

Comment: I found the link in the uVision page. I'll make an aswer for the other guys around. Thank you for your contribution, special thanks to the @old_timer who point me the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the uVision: http://www.keil.com/support/docs/2824.htm.

uVision is doing some additional optimization so watching local variables is not reliable.

Comment: Turn off optimisations when debugging, I would.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did no post the whole function from this fragment I can only guess:

1. There are only assignments to the local variable, but it is not used anywhere in your program and it is probably removed from the generated code.
2. Don't look for errors in the compiler. They are quite good and I have not found any (I am a very active coder). Always when someone says : "this is disassembly listing, the compiler is wrong", the mistake is done somewhere by the asker. Forget about disassembly when you debug your program. You just waste you time.

Comment: sure filt is read, I'll update my question. Thank you for your hint. I'm not looking for any errors in the compiler, neighter I'm saying that the compiler is wrong. I'm trying to localize the error and asking questions about the strange behaviour.

Comment: @judoka_acl post the complete function call. If functions works in the certain circumstances it does not mean that it will work in another. Bugs are quite often more complex to unveil.

Comment: the error is localized exactly in the code I've posted. If you insist I can share it to you personaly, but I'm 1000% sure that the problem is not in the rest of the function. I'm considering now the idea that the debugger is showing wrong address, and that the problem is not at all in the code.